# Prove that there exists a nonempty subset $ I$ of $ \{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $ \sum_{i\in I}{\frac {1}{b_i}}$ is an integer

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, elementary-proofs

> Let $ a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ and $ b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ be positive integers such that any integer $ x$ satisfies at least one congruence $ x\equiv a_i\pmod {b_i}$ for some $ i$. Prove that there exists a nonempty subset $ I$ of $ \{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $ \sum_{i\in I}{\frac {1}{b_i}}$ is an integer. - (Problems from the book, chapter 17)

This is a solution I have found on AoPS:

> Solution a la Vess: Consider $ \prod_j(e^{2\pi i\frac{x-a_j}{b_j}}-1)=\sum_I\pm e^{2\pi i (A_I x+B_I)}$. Looking at the left hand side, we see that its average over $ \mathbb Z$ (understood as $ \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1{2N+1}\sum_{-N}^N$) is $ 0$. Looking at the right hand side, we see that if no $ A_I$ with $ I\ne\varnothing$ is an integer, then it is $ (-1)^n$.

Is this answer correct? If so, how can I understand this solution ? What is $A_I$ and $B_I$ ? Are there any other solutions for this problem ?

Comment: This is a result of Ming-Zhi Zhang in 1989.

Comment: The use of abbreviations, possibly known in one given country, makes it a bit tricky to track the quotation.

Comment: @YCor if you are talking about AoPS, this is probably artofproblemsolving.com

Comment: A related comment. It also turns out that, the smallest $n$ for which an $n$-covering system (namely, system of $n$-congruences, $x\equiv a_i\pmod{b_i}$ with $b_1<\cdots<b_n$ such that, every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ obeys at least one of them) is precisely 5, and an old Turkish olympiad problem.

Answer (score 7):

This is a result of Ming-Zhi Zhang in 1989 [J. Sichuan Univ. (Nat. Sci. Ed.) 26(1989), Special Issue 185-188]. For my simple proof and extensions of this result, one may consult [my talk](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/Utalk.pdf), the survey [Problems and Results on Covering Systems](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/Cover.pdf) and [my 1995 paper in Acta Arith.](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/26a.pdf)

Comment: I don't like a book using a known result as an exercise without proper citation.

Comment: But the book might just ignore that the result was known. It's also plausible that it was initially proved before 1989.

Comment: Dear Zhi-Wei, the book mentions the author (M. Zhang). Usually such books do not contain the full references to the original papers.

Answer (score 5):

Vess's solution is correct (as we could expect from him).
After expanding the brackets, we get an alternating sum of the exponents, for a set $I\subset \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ we have a summand $(-1)^{n-|I|} e^{2\pi i (A_Ix+B_I)}$,
where $A_I=\sum_{j\in I} \frac1{b_j}$, $B_I=-\sum_{j\in I} \frac{a_j}{b_j}$.

You may finish it by averaging not over large segments of integers and taking the limit, but over $x=0,1,\dots,lcm(b_1,\dots,b_n)-1$.

Essentially the same argument may be read as follows. Denote $N=lcm(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ and consider the polynomial $f(z)=\prod_{j=1}^n (z^{N/b_j}-e^{2\pi i a_j/b_j})$. You are given that any root of $z^N-1$ is a root of $f$, so $f$ is divisible by $z^N-1$. Expand the brackets in $f$ and reduce it modulo $z^N-1$. This is the same as reducing each exponent of $z$ modulo $N$. Since we get 0 after total reduction, $f$ should contain some exponent divisible by $N$ other than the constant term. This is what we need.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Can you explain why if no $ A_I$ with $ I\ne\varnothing$ is an integer, then the right hand side is $ (-1)^n$ ?

Comment: Because if $A_I\notin \mathbb{Z}$, we have $A_I=p/q$ where $p,q$ are coprime and $q>1$ is a divisor of $lcm(b_1,\dots,b_n)$.  Then $\sum e^{2\pi i A_I\cdot x}$ when $x$ runs over $q$ consecutive integers equals 0.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov, please visit the links in my answer. Vess's and your explanations are essential the same as my earlier observations mentioned in the linked talks.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov, please visit the links in my answer. Vess's and your explanations are essential the same as my earlier observations mentioned in the linked talks.

Comment: About your solution,$f$ indeed should contain some exponent divisible by N other than the constant term, however what if the exponent can be equal to $\frac{N^k}{b_1b_2...b_k}$, with some $k>1$?

Comment: @color  See the lemma in my paper http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/17m.pdf

Comment: @Zhi-WeiSun many thanks for the link to your talk! Looks very interesting for me.